# How to disable video in Sinch

Tags: ios, sinch

I'm implementing a video chat using [Sinch](http://sinch.com), but I can't find a way to disable the outgoing video once the call has started.

Is this documented somewhere?

And if it's not supported by the SDK, is there a way (even an hackish one) to "intercept" the video stream and prevent it to be sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there's no official way to do this in the SDK, but here's a hack that works as expected.

Long story short, with some runtime "magic" we can intercept the `AVCaptureSessoin` initiated by Sinch and control it.

Here's how:

```
extension AVCaptureSession {
  public override class func initialize() {
    struct Static {
      static var token: dispatch_once_t = 0
    }

    // make sure this isn't a subclass
    if self !== AVCaptureSession.self {
      return
    }

    dispatch_once(&Static.token) {
      let originalSelector = #selector(AVCaptureSession.init)
      let swizzledSelector = #selector(AVCaptureSession.hd_init)

      let originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(self, originalSelector)
      let swizzledMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(self, swizzledSelector)

      let didAddMethod = class_addMethod(self, originalSelector, method_getImplementation(swizzledMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(swizzledMethod))

      if didAddMethod {
        class_replaceMethod(self, swizzledSelector, method_getImplementation(originalMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(originalMethod))
      } else {
        method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swizzledMethod);
      }
    }
  }

  @nonobjc static var hd_currentSession: AVCaptureSession? = nil

  func hd_init() {
    hd_init() // at runtime this is the original `init` implementation
    AVCaptureSession.hd_currentSession = self
  }

}
```

A brief explanation: the first part is just basic runtime swizzling of two methods, nothing specific to this implementation.

Namely, we're replacing the implementation of `AVCaptureSession.init` with our own `AVCaptureSession.hd_init` (`hd` is just any prefix to avoid potential clashing of method names).

> **NOTE**
>
> In `hd_init` we're calling `hd_init`. This is a bit mind-bending, but it's how swizzling works: at the time we execute that piece of code `hd_init` has been replaced by the original `init`, so we're actually calling the original implementation, which is what we want.

Our custom implementation of `init` has just the purpose of storing a static reference to the instance, which we'll refer to as `hd_currentSession`.

And we're done!

Now from anywhere in the app we can get a reference to the current `AVCaptureSession` and stop it / start it at will.

For instance

```
func toggleVideo() {
  if let session = AVCapture.hd_currentSession {
    if session.running {
      session.stopRunning()
    } else {
      session.startRunning()
    }
  }  
}
```

At any time after the Sinch video stream has started, we can simply call `toggleVideo()`

> **CAVEAT**
>
> Stopping the capture session will cause the video to "freeze" to the last frame. I haven't worked around this issue on iOS side, but I've noticed that on the Javascript API you get a `"muted"` event on the video `MediaTrack`. Given this, you can - for example - hide the video on the other client's side using the `onmuted` event.